# AJAX - How To Display Different Columns Upon Selection

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am using AJAX to fetch data from MySQL Database. The way it works: user selects an item from drop down menu, and data is then displayed. However, my question: is there a way to display DIFFERENT columns within the SAME drop down menu? In other words, the first selection in the drop down menu displays first name and last name and the second selection in the drop down menu displays first name last name and also suffix. It seems that it's not possible to include a column in one selection of the drop down menu but not in another. But wanted to at least ask the question to see if i missed something. My two scripts:

**index.php:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a person:</option>
  <option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
  <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
  <option value="3">Joseph Swanson</option>
  <option value="4">Glenn Quagmire</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**getuser.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','peter','abc123','my_db');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Hometown</th>
<th>Job</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Hometown'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Job'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. The selections in the menu are different people, why should it display different columns?

Comment: You shouldn't be returning a whole HTML page from the AJAX script. You can't have `<!DOCTYPE>` and `<head>` inside a `DIV` in the body.

Comment: You shold just return the HTML for the table.

Comment: For example, if in the drop down menu I select "Peter Griffin", it will display all the columns I have echoed out in the second script. But that is also true if I select "Lois Griffin" or any other selection. My goal is to echo different columns for each selection.

Comment: What is the criteria it uses for which columns to display? Just put that logic into the PHP script.

Comment: Use `if` statements in the PHP script to skip columns for some selections.

Comment: Can you give me a small example or let me know where i would put it? Much appreciated!

Comment: Answer my question: what is the criteria that governs which columns should be shown for which selections?

Comment: So there's no general rule, you just want to hard-code q=1 means first/last, q=2 means first/last/suffix, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `if` or `switch` statement to change the HTML that you return.

```
echo "<table>";

switch ($q) {
case "1":
    echo "<tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Hometown</th>
    <th>Job</th>
    </tr>";
    break;
case "2":
    echo "<tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Suffix</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Hometown</th>
    <th>Job</th>
    </tr>";
    break;
default:
    echo "<tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Hometown</th>
    <th>Job</th>
    </tr>";
    break;
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
    if ($q == 2) {
        echo "<td>" . $row['Suffix'] . "</td>";
    }
    if ($q < 3) {
        echo "<td>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "<td>" . $row['Hometown'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Job'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a solution that will work in the long run. If you generate the option list from the database, the ID numbers will likely change over time.